# My redirect() function doesn't work using CodeIgniter

Tags: php

I want to create a home page, it contains a dropdown list which has 2 options: New Feature and New Project, and a Submit button.

When u selects New Feature option and click submit button, system redirects to a page call Feature page

When u selects New Project option and click submit button, system redirects to a page call Project page

My problem: the `redirect()` function does not work, system redirects to a while page

Please see my code:

```
public function home() 
{   

         $this->load->helper('url');

        if ($this->input->post ()) 
        {
            if ($_POST ['ProductType'] == "feature") {

                echo "sdfsdfsd 1";
                redirect(base_url('feature/index'));
            } else {
                echo "sdfsdfsd 2";
                redirect(base_url('project/index'));
            }
        } else 
        {
            $this->load->helper ( "form" );
            $data ['title'] = 'Welcome to Estimation tool';
            $data ['header'] = 'Welcome to Estimation tool';

            $data ['options'] = array (
                    'feature' => 'New Feature',
                    'project' => 'New Project' 
            );

            $this->load->view ( 'welcome_message', $data );
        }
    }
```

I appreciated if you could help me to solve my problem!

Comment: Take away public infront of the function

Comment: No :( It still displays the white blank page

Comment: Post a picture on what it looks like the error

Comment: And then take away base_url on the redirect

Comment: I also tried redirect('feature', 'refresh');, redirect('feature') but it doesn't work too

Comment: Send me all code to my email.

Comment: Yes please wait. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: also note `redirect` won't work after `echo` or any output

Comment: It displays echo "sdfsdfsd 1"; for a second then it refresh the page and the URL displays as: http://::1/Estimation/Feature/index

Comment: can you check error log if there any error like header alredy sent etc

Comment: I checked and see nothing

Comment: When I copy my code and run on another desktop, it run without error. I don't know why ...

Comment: I helped you, but you voted the answer which is same in my answer. I'm the first who answered it  correctly. And you voted for guys who just copy my Answer!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to include the `base_url` inside redirect.

```
redirect('controller_name/method_name');
```

Comment: What is your POST name??

Comment: here :  if ($this->input->post ())

Comment: I'm  not sure that I can understand your question :(...I'm very new in programing

Comment: If you alredy have 150 reputation  and up, you can vote answers by clicking the arrow up besides the answer :)